# .htaccess rewrites for subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to make all URLs of the site belong to the root domain.com even the assets, and only categories in sub domains

**example**

```
domain.com/
domain.com/join.php
domain.com/admin/
games.domain.com/
games.domain.com/arcade/
games.domain.com/arcade/10.html
```

each of these url take from ===

```
domain.com/ === index.php
domain.com/join.php === join.php
domain.com/admin/ === /admin/
games.domain.com/ === main_categories.php?slug=games
games.domain.com/arcade/ === sub_categories.php?slug=games&cat=arcade
games.domain.com/arcade/10.html  === view.php?slug=games&cat=arcade&id=10
```

I have this code but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain.com 
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main_categories.php?prefix=%1 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?((index|news|photos|videos|articles)\.html)?$ sub_categories.php?prefix=$1&type=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?(.*)?.html$ view.php?prefix=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You should use a MVC Architecture. Doesn't have to be object oriented.

Comment: its too late to do that, the app already bult

Comment: You said "i want to make **all urls** of the site belong to the root domain.com". How will apache know the difference between what you consider a category and what's not a category? You will need to narrow that down and exclude certain URIs then it will be easier to create the rules.

Comment: only sub domains are the categories

Comment: i want make something like RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?((index|news|photos|videos|articles)\.html)?$

Comment: so these are the sub categories `index|news|photos|videos|articl‌​es`? Because you didn't really list them out.

Comment: Also is the subdomain always `games.example.com`?

Comment: no, its a test value of categoty name from db

Comment: what about RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/? can you make it work, just give me the syntax

Comment: I'm still not understanding your requirement. So the subdomains are dynamic and based on what you enter, it will become a category?

Comment: like this, i replaced the value directly to make it easy for understand , each word in the right and left its just variables games.domain.com/arcade/ === sub_categories.php?slug=games&cat=arcade or in normal moded (*.).domain.com/(*.)/ === sub_categories.php?slug=$1&cat=$2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you at all. First, you will need to update your Apache config or Virtual Host `ServerAlias` to include any subdomains `*.example.com` you want Apache to respond to. You will probably need to make a **wildcard subdomain DNS entry** so it knows where to send the request when someone types in `games.example.com`.

Then you will need to make a rule to exclude `www` and `non-www` by using these rules below.

```
#games.domain.com/ === main_categories.php?slug=games
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ main_categories.php?slug=%1 [L,QSA]

#games.domain.com/arcade/ === sub_categories.php?slug=games&cat=arcade
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ sub_categories.php?slug=%1&cat=$1 [L,QSA]

#games.domain.com/arcade/10.html  === view.php?slug=games&cat=arcade&id=10
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ view.php?slug=%1&cat=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: its not worked,but seems good but i think there are some errors such as (example\com) where is the dot?

Comment: I corrected the syntax but it still may not work if you haven't updated Apache and Dns.

Comment: I'm using some config and the localhost reads the subdomains but its not working

Comment: It does work because I also tested it. It could be your config on localhost. You can test these rules http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 2):

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.ru$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)\.html$ /view.php?slug=%1&cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.ru$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /sub_categories.php?slug=%1&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.ru$ 
RewriteRule ^$ /main_categories.php?slug=%1 [L]
```

If your Apache configuration does not do this for you, add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php
```

Comment: games is not a subdomain, its just a value from db, i can not make it constant

Comment: Does 'games' the same in subdomain name and query var ?

Comment: i want it like RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(*.).domain.com$